# how to select images and divs created by jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, select, slideshow

i'm using boxskitter slideshow and it creates some divs with class "box_clone" after the first animation happens and puts images inside them. I want to select these images to change their size i've tried this

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var w = $("body").width();
var h = $("body").height();
alert(w);
$(".box_skitter.box_skitter_large,.container_skitter").css({"width":w,"height":h});
$(".box_clone img").each(function(index, element) {
    $(this).css({"width":w,"height":h});
});
$(".box_skitter.box_skitter_large img").css({"width":w,"height":h});
});
```

but it didn't work any help?

Comment: It would help to see the code surrounding this snippet. If w and h are always the same you can simply use `$(".box_clone img").css({width:w,height:h});` to apply to all images at once

Comment: end of page before </body>

Comment: I keep looking at the code in inspect element and these clone divs show up after the first animation heppens after 4 seconds

Comment: But it sounds like you need to hook into an event of `boxskitter` that occurs when the classes have been added. Where is `boxskitter` being run?

Comment: Which specific boxskitter slideshow are you using? There seems to be a lot matching that Google search.

Comment: width is 1663 and height is 1000 but images stick to 1280 width and 900 height

Comment: http://www.skitter-slider.net/

Comment: skitter-slider has an `onLoad` event you can hook into when you start skitter-slider. please provide your skitter-slider start code for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

skitter-slider.net has a `onLoad` event you can put your code in. I'm awaiting your actual code, but it should be something like this:

```
var w = $("body").width();
var h = $("body").height();
$('.box_skitter_large').skitter({ onLoad: function(self) { 
      $(".box_skitter.box_skitter_large,.container_skitter").css({width:w,height:h});
      $(".box_clone img").css({width:w,height:h});
      $(".box_skitter.box_skitter_large img").css({width:w,height:h});
    } 
});
```

The theory being that skitter calls this callback function *after* it has made all its changes to the DOM structure.

As `self`, passed in the onLoad, is likely to be the element skitter is connected to, you may be able to simplify your selector code to use that + your descendant element selectors

*Really need a JSFiddle mock-up to test this if it does not work 1st time.*

### Alternative CSS:

As you appear to be making the entire slider and all it's elements the size of the page, you may be able to do it all with CSS. Something like this:

```
   html,body,.box_skitter.box_skitter_large,.container_skitter,.box_clone img, .box_skitter.box_skitter_large img{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: http://mawk3y.net/skitter/ please wait till the animation happens. there are 5 photos 1663x900 there's something wrong with the width

Comment: It may have an upper size limit, but your design is currently not responding to browser size changes anyway. Try the CSS solution mentioned instead for starters as that will hopefully respond to changes with no code. *So much depends on how they wrote their plugin*.

Comment: i've tried this but didn't work but thanks for your help so far

Comment: I have usually found I needed to tweak the source (or switch plugins) when I hit problems like this. *(Eventually I wrote my own slideshow instead but that is written in TypeScript and currently unreleased).* They all have their own features and merits.